# Are angular-material modules automatically tree-shaked?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I saw angular-material individual modules imported in two ways.

1. import all angular-material modules (MatButtonModule, MatRadioModule, etc.) into a huge angular-material.module and then import that module into any Angular module that needs some angular-material stuff.
2. Import the individual material modules into their respective modules, where there are used. For example I will import the ReactiveFormsModule in my RegistrationModule (where user fills out the registration form), but I will not import it in other lazy loaded modules, where there are no forms.

The second option seems to me tedious and hard to maintain, therefore I prefer the first option. However, I would like to keep the final bundle size as small as humanly possible.

Which brings me to my question:

**Are angular-material modules automatically tree-shaked?**

In other words - when I import the huge angular.material.module.ts into my lazy loaded module - will the final bundle contain the angular-material modules that are not used in that respective module?

Should I stick to the second option, or is it OK to jam it all into the huge angular-material.module?

Comment: This question has been closed because it's supposedly 'opinion-based'. I don't think that the fact of angular-material being tree-shake-able or not is an opinion. It's a binary fact - either it is treeshakeable, or not.

Answer (score 4):

No, its bad, dont do this.

Here is research on this topic: https://indepth.dev/stop-using-shared-material-module/

Basically if such magic would be possible, nobody will bother to split material library to tone of modules and in general everybody will make one giant module and hope compiler will understand what to do with this.

Maybe in future, with more Ivy-related things it will be possible, but now, it will maybe exlude some services and components or pure functions, maybe not.

And even if it will - its in general bad practice to write code, that logically should not be there.

Comment: so you suggest I continue import individual angular-material modules into my respective angular modules. And not using angular-material module at all? I worked on a few projects and quite high ranking companies used the angular-material module approach.

Comment: nice article, the only think is not confirmed for me is what angular version is using to do the test (Angular 9+ with tree shaking engine (Ivy)?)

Comment: If I understand correctly: Even if you only import individual Material modules in your modules, you increase the size of the app for each module. Because the Material component are not resued. For 10 modules, you have 10 copies of that components. In other words: The Angular Material team suggest you to only use one huge app.module. It's ridiculous... Is there really no way to provide Material in global scope for the whole app without shared module? Or a kind of tree-shaking, etc?